# Passing Member Function Pointer into a Template

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointer-to-member

First of all sorry for the title being confusing. Here's my OOP setup. I have base class Base, and two pure virtual functions add and multi. Then I have derived classes D1 and D2 and I implement the add and multi functions. I want to have a template function, that can have the flexibility that can switch between D1 D2 and calling add or multi functions. I googled around and someone people saying I should use function pointers but some others say it does not work with pure virtual functions.

```
class Base
{ double data; //data member
  Base(double d):data(d){}; 
  virtual double add() = 0; 
  virtual double multi() = 0; 
}
class D1::public Base
{ D1(double d): Base(d) {}; //calling base class constructor
  double add() {return data+1;} ;
  double multi() {return data*2;} ;
}
class D2::public Base
{ D2(double d): Base(d) {}; //calling base class constructor
  double add() {return data+3;} ;
  double multi() {return data*4;} ;
}
//now I want to have a template function that give me flexibility to construct D1 or D2 and calling add or multi.
template <typename T, typename F> 
void testFun(double num)
{ T tmp(num); //create object either D1 or D2;
  cout << T->F() << endl; //calling either add or multi;
}
int main()
{ testFun<D1, D1.add()>(double x = 5); 
//i know passing in D1.add() is wrong i don't know how to fix, hopefully you know what I am trying to achieve
  return 0;}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing about virtual member functions that makes pointers to member functions not work.  You can invoke a pointer to a pure virtual function if the object being invoked on is a pointer/reference to an object that has an actual implementation.

It looks like you're getting tripped up on the syntax of exactly how to pass a pointer-to-member-function in the first place.

Also note that virtual dispatch wouldn't even be used here since the type of object being used is known at compile time.

```
template <typename T> 
void testFun(double num, double (T::*fn)())
{
    T tmp(num);
    std::cout << (tmp.*fn)() << std::endl;
}
```

Here, `fn` is a pointer to a member function of `T` that accepts no arguments and returns a `double` value.  You can invoke it like so:

```
testFun<D1>(5, &D1::add);
```

Note some other errors with the example code you've given:

- You specify base types with `::` when you should use `:`. For example: `class D1 : public Base`.
- You use `class` but never specify an access modifier, which means all members are implicitly `private`.  For the purposes of the demo, changing them to `struct` (which defaults to `public` access) fixes this.
- You need a semicolon after a class/struct definition.

[Here is a demo of the working code](https://godbolt.org/z/qxszY8).

---

Just for the sake of completeness, [here is a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6qMEsY) showing that you *can* use a pointer to a pure-virtual member function to invoke on a reference/pointer to a derived type.  The code has to be adjusted to use a `D1` or `D2` object through a reference of `Base` for the dispatch to be dynamic.  This example looks like:

```
template <typename T> 
void testFun(double num, double (Base::*fn)())
{
    T tmpConcrete(num);
    Base & tmp = tmpConcrete;
    std::cout << (tmp.*fn)() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    testFun<D1>(5, &Base::add);
}
```

(Of course, here it's a bit silly to use a pointer to a `Base` member when the generic code knows what `T` is, but it proves the point that it's possible.)

Comment: Thanks for showing me result, I really appreciate it. One more question, if my 'multi 'function is 'void' instead of 'double', then how can I change my template function definition?

Comment: @HGWantToLearn The signature for a member function pointer is `returntype (ClassType::*ptr)(arguments...)` so just fill that out. For example, if the class type is `T` and the function returns `void` and takes no arguments, it would be `void (T::*ptr)()` to declare a pointer-to-member named `ptr`. In the first sample I gave, the pointer name is `fn`, the class type being invoked on is `T`, the return type is `double`, and there are no arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking if I can use something like "auto (T::*fn)()" in this case I only keep one signature and that could work for both double/void/int etc. Apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: @HGWantToLearn You could just make the whole second argument a template parameter. [Then the compiler can deduce it](https://godbolt.org/z/n984jW).